# Renaming the '_' variable in Python

Tags: python, alias

I recently learned about the builtin variable `_` in the python shell, the purpose of which is to store the last console answer. For example:

```
>>> 4 + 7
11
>>> _
11
>>> Test = 4
>>> Test + 3
7
>>> _
7
```

Being a longtime TI-Basic programmer, I'm far more comfortable with thinking of this variable as `Ans` instead of `_`. (Yes, I know it's merely personal preference, but it's an interesting question in any case.)

**Question:** How do I set up my `Ans` variable so that its value is *always* the same as the `_` variable?

---

It's not as simple as just doing `Ans = _`, as this shell log shows:

```
>>> "test string"
'test string'
>>> _
'test string'
>>> Ans = _
>>> Ans
'test string'
>>> list('Other String')
['O', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
>>> _
['O', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
>>> Ans
'test string'
```

Comment: You can probably look at the shell source code and hack something in...

Comment: You basically want `Ans = _` to run after every line you type.

Comment: It might be easier to get IPython to do this than regular Python, since it already has a bunch of hooks you can customize...

Comment: But the really short answer is just "get used to it", instead of bringing your preconceptions to a new language.

Comment: Python is not TI-BASIC, sometimes it's easier to just get used to it.

Comment: Admittedly true, but my purpose in this was simply to inquire as to how the system works. The choice of names came from my own experience. Had I wanted to, `Hamlet_king_of_the_Danes` is, syntactically, just as feasible as `Ans`.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend the "get used to it" option, but if you really want to fiddle with this, you can customize [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), the function responsible for setting `_`:

```
import builtins
import sys

def displayhook(value):
    if value is not None:
        # The built-in displayhook is a bit trickier than it seems,
        # so we delegate to it instead of inlining equivalent handling.
        sys.__displayhook__(value)
        builtins.Ans = value

sys.displayhook = displayhook
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Yeah, I mixed up the modules.

Comment: Interesting +1 , why isn’t _ in the globals() dict?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's in `builtins`. I believe this is at least in part due to not wanting to stomp on a user-defined `_` variable.