# Is it possible to "customize" python?

Tags: python-3.x

Can I change the core functionality of Python, for example, rewrite it to use `say("Hello world")` instead of `print("Hello world")`?
If this is possible, how can this be done?

Comment: You can do `say = print` then use `say("hello")` henceforth. I'm not sure what you mean by rewriting the core functionality of Python, though. Please elaborate.

Comment: Think of python as a language that you speak with other developers.  While you can make up your own word, getting it in the dictionary is difficult.  You will work with other developers on projects and they won't know what you mean when you say("thing").

Comment: @Back2Basics That is actually a *really* good description of programming. It's not that you can't do it, its that you can't make everybody else do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a few possibilities as to how to accomplish this. I've arranged them in order of how much programming is needed/how obnoxious they are:

### Renaming builtins

If, as in your example, you are simply more comfortable using `say()` or `printf()` than `print()`, then you can, as others have answered, just alias the builtin function to your own function with something like `say=print`.

### Rewriting builtins

Let's pretend we don't trust the official implementation of `print()` and we want to implement our own. A lot of the internals in Python such as `stdin` are contained in the `sys` library. You could, if you wanted, implement your own. I asked a question a couple years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50218274/8954291) that discussed how to rename the `_` variable to `ans` which might be illuminating to take a look at.

### Sending your code through a preprocessor

Ok, so `gcc` doesn't *require* C code as input. If you use the right precompiler flags, then you could get away with evaluating `#define` macros in your source code before you send it to python. Technically a valid answer, but obnoxious as heck.

### Writing modules in another language

Cython (python written in C) can have modules written for it in C. You could build a wrapper for `printf` in C (or assembly, if you'd rather) and use that library in your python code.

### Recompiling Python

Unfortunately, doing the above is not possible with all tokens. What if, in a fit of fancy, we'd like to use `whilst` loops instead of `while` loops? The only way to accomplish this is actually altering the functioning of python itself. Now, this isn't for the faint of heart or the new programmer. Compilers are *really* complicated.

Since, however, Python is open source and you can download the source code [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/), in theory, you could go into the compiler and manually make all the edits you want, then compile your version of python and use that. By no means would your code be portable (as essentially you'd be making a fork of python) but you *could technically* do it.

Or just conform to the Python standards. That works too.

### Writing a PEP

Python is a living language. It's constantly being updated. The ruling body of "What gets included" is the BDFL-delegate and the Council, but anyone can write a Python Enhancement Proposal that proposes to change the language in some way. Most features in Python started out as a PEP. See [PEP 0001](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/) for more details.

Comment: Interesting! Is it possible to rewrite builtins and provide the altered code in a package? Like some kind of "mod" for python?

Comment: Builtins are, well... built in. If you rewrite them, then any other code you try to import might break because it's running on a different python than it expects. That being said, you can do whatever you wish in your own namespace.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can just write 
`say = print
say("hello")`

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: i dont see any answer all comments

Comment: Comments are still answers. ggorlen deserves credit for being the first one to respond with that answer. IMO, the proper behavior in this situation is to wait 24 hours to give a chance to turn the comment into an actual answer, then after that mark your answer as Community Wiki unless you can provide significantly more insight into the problem.